# Linear Referencing Methods: Station Equation origins

Tags: references, linear-referencing, gis-principle, history, research

I am working in the pipelines field, and I get in touch with the concept of the linear referencing methods, specifically with station equation method.

I had to do research about this method, I'm quite confident about my understanding of the topic and the concept associated to it, but a set questions came to my mind:

- Where did this topic originate?
- Who proposed it?
- When was it proposed?

After an intensive Google search I have not found a clue about the history of station equation method. I got a lot of technical documents that describe the concepts and how this concept works, but not its origins.

I am seeking any book or paper suggestions

Comment: It goes back to 1620 when Chains were used in measuring accuracy - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_%28unit%29

Comment: thanks Fezter, this is a good start for me but I mean about the method of station equation used in pipelines surveys